# My SKVideoNode in SpriteKit is automatically playing on scene load

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm adding an `SKVideoNode` to a scene programmatically in `didMove(to view: SKView)` like this:

```
  mainCircleVideo = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "pipSmile.mp4")
  mainCircleVideo.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width*0.6, height: self.size.width*0.6)
  mainCircleVideo.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
  addChild(mainCircleVideo)
```

`mainCircleVideo` is declared in the class (which is an `SKScene` as I'm using SpriteKit)

When I transition to this scene - the video automatically plays.  I'm using

```
self.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: fadeTransition)
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

**UPDATE**: I'm not sure why but removing the fadeTransition seems to fix it

Comment: You can control playback using the node’s play() and pause() methods

Comment: UPDATE: I'm not sure why but removing the fadeTransition seems to fix it ...

Comment: Thanks @LalKrishna but the play() and pause() wasn't working

Comment: did you used `mainCircleVideo.pause()` just after you added it as a child?

Comment: yes I tried that - didn't work either ....

Comment: When using transitions, did move to view is fired immediately.    Set pauseIncomingScene on the transition instance to true to stop the video from playing during transition

Comment: thanks @Knight0fDragon.  Even if didMoveToView is fired it shouldn't play the video until it's instructed to do so? The didMoveToView contains no play function it just adds the video node as a child. Play is triggered via touches began in my case

Comment: It works on the isPaused variable,  and that gets turned off on the scene during a transition, which means all nodes a child of it also get it turned off

Comment: so I used both transitionName.pausesIncomingScene = true   AND   videoNode.pause()  (after the child was added) and this still doesn't pause the incoming video.